# How to install openpyxl==2.2.0b1

Tags: python, installation, pip, openpyxl

How to install openpyxl==2.2.0b1 this version,
I tried, `pip install openpyxl==2.2.0b1`

It throws,

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl==2.2.0b1 (from versions: 1.1.0, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.2.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9, 2.4.10, 2.4.11, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4, 2.5.5, 2.5.6, 2.5.7, 2.5.8, 2.5.9)
>   No matching distribution found for openpyxl==2.2.0b1

Please help me to install this `openpyxl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the `b1` stands for beta-1 which means this was a beta version before becoming the latest stable version, so when the requirement was written 2.2.0 wasn't fully released yet on PyPi, but now it is so you can use it normally. For the same functionality you should just use.

```
pip install openpyxl==2.2.0
```

Comment: @MohamedThasinah if you're happy with the solution don't forget to upvote and mark it as correct so that others can see it's been answered (and give me POINTS!)